# How to append tuples to a dictionary without list or having brackets around it

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have the following code:

```
G = {
 'A': {('1', 2), ('C', 5)},
 'B': {('C', 6), ('D', 1), ('E', 3), ('A', 2)},
 'C': {('F',  8), ('A', 5), ('B', 6)},
 'D': {('E', 4)},
 'E': {('G', 9)},
 'F': {('G', 7), ('C', 2)},
 'G': {('E', 9), ('F', 7)}
}
```

Say I want to replace the nested dict key 'A' values with **('D', 7), ('E', 8)** using a for loop, my approach was to append each of the tuple into a **list** and then G['A'] = **list**
but this would give me **'A': {[('D', 7), ('E', 8)]}** with brackets ([,]) within

Is there a way to append tuples into a dictionary such that without having brackets

Comment: Lists aren't hashable, so you can't put them inside sets. Could you post your complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the existing (i.e. `G['A'] = set()`) or if you want to remove some, use `.remove`.

And, use `.add` to add a value because the values of the `dict` are sets.

```
G['A'] = set()
G['A'].add(('D', 7))
G['A'].add(('E', 8))
```

output:

```
{'A': {('D', 7), ('E', 8)},
 'B': {('A', 2), ('C', 6), ('D', 1), ('E', 3)},
 'C': {('A', 5), ('B', 6), ('F', 8)},
 'D': {('E', 4)},
 'E': {('G', 9)},
 'F': {('C', 2), ('G', 7)},
 'G': {('E', 9), ('F', 7)}}
```

Alternatively, you could assign a key directly to a set literal, as:
`G['A'] = {('D', 7), ('E', 8)}`

The difference between a dict and a set is that while both use curly braces `{` `}`, dictionaries have key:value pairs (like `G` does), while sets only have values.  This is why the value of `G['A']` is a set and not a nested dict.